# Java (Groovy) LDAP Non-ASCII Characters

Tags: java, groovy, ldap, non-ascii-characters

I've been googling my ass off without any success. So I came here. Hope someone can help me out!
Im using Groovy to do some LDAP searches but when a person has å, ä or ö in their names I get for example Jens R√§fteg√•rd.
I've tried:

new String(attrs.get("name")?.get(0)?.getBytes(), "UTF-8")

And even tried:

def charsets = Charset.availableCharsets()
charsets.each() { key, value ->
    value.aliases().each() { alias ->
        println new String(attrs.get("name")?.get(0)?.getBytes(), alias)
    }
}

Anyone got a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone's interested it was the Grails Shiro-plugin whom messed with the encodings. Fixed now!